# Adding/Removing items from a list as a property of a model in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using the guide found here http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style and am using MVC2.

I've got it working with a controller method as such:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateStockRequest(StockRequestModel viewModel, List<StockRequestModel.StockRequestItem> items)
{
    viewModel.Items = items;

    // Validate the request and submit it
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

As you can see, even though my Model contains an `Items` method, i've had to add an `items` parameter, as the property on the model wasn't getting populated.

I've tried changing `items` to `Items` in the `BeginCollectionItem` method and have tried various other values but I can't get it to work without adding the seperate `items` parameter in the controller method.

**tl;dr:** How can I add/remove/edit items in a list property of a model, from a view?

---

### View

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Items[0].Item )%></td>
            <td><%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Items[0].Quantity )%></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="editorRows">
        <% foreach (var item in Model.Items)
           {
               Html.RenderPartial("StockRequestItemEditor", item);
        }%>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><%= Html.ActionLink("Add Item...", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })%></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#addItem").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.href,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            </script>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

### Partial View

```
<tr>
    <% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items")) { %>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ComboBoxFor(m => m.Item,
                                 null,
                                 Url.Action("Products", "Data", new { area = (string)null }),
                                 Model.Item,
                                 2)%>
        </td>
        <td><%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity)%></td>
    <% } %>
</tr>
```

Comment: Updated with view and partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a view model?

```
public class StockRequestModel 
{
    public List<StockRequestItem> Items { get; set; }

    ... some other properties
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateStockRequest(StockRequestModel viewModel)
{
    // TODO: do something with viewModel.Items ...

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and inside your view:

```
<div class="editorRow">
    <% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("Items")) { %>
        ...
    <% } %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot but maybe this is the problem:

```
Html.RenderPartial("StockRequestItemEditor", item);
```

I noticed when inspecting the viewModel in the POST action that it would have the correct number of items in the collection, but they would all be null.  That suggests to me that this is a prefixing issue with the model binder.  So maybe something like this will work:

```
var dictPrefix = new ViewDataDictionary();
dictPrefix.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "SomePrefix";

Html.RenderPartial("StockRequestItemEditor", item, dictPrefix);
```

I don't think `RenderPartial()` passes along the prefix without using this overload (might be wrong though).  I'm not completely sure how the bind prefixing works, so I don't actually know what the name would be, but it seems like it's relevant here.  The collection definitely has the correct number of items for me, but none of them are correctly bound.

Hopefully this will be enough to push someone else to giving you the right answer.

Comment: "SomePrefix" should probably be something like `"Items[" + i + "]"`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this information. My understanding is that the  `BeginCollectionItem` method is basically doing this (only using a GUID as index so as to allow things to be added/removed).